# How to display only 12 hours of hourly temp from OpenWeatherMap?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I’m having a brain block right now and I can’t figure out how to display only 12 hours of hourly temperature rather than the 48 hours with the OpenWeatherMap API OneCall. I've tried messing around with the for-in loop but not having any luck.

Here is my ViewModel

```
class WeatherModel: ObservableObject {
    
    //Declare published property wrapper, that when the the property value changes, we want to notifty anyone who is observing it
    @Published var weatherData: Weather?
    @AppStorage("cityName") var cityName = ""


    init(){
        getWeatherData(cityName)
    }
    //Init method gets run when a new instance of WeatherModel is created
    
    
    //MARK: - OpenWeatherMap API methods
    
    
    func getWeatherData(_ cityName: String){
        CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(cityName){(placemarks, error ) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let lat = placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate.latitude,
                let lon = placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate.longitude {
                //first is the first element of the collection
                let weatherUrlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=\(lat)&lon=\(lon)&exclude=minutely,daily,alerts&units=imperial&appid=\(Constants.apiKey)"
                
                let weatherUrl = URL(string: weatherUrlString)
                guard weatherUrl != nil else {
                    return
                }
                
                let request = URLRequest(url: weatherUrl!)
                
                //Create a URL session
                
                let session = URLSession.shared
                let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    
                    do{
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        var result = try decoder.decode(Weather.self, from: data!)
                        //parsing the weather data into the constant, result
                        
                        //Add UUId's to the hourly weather objects. Use the variable Result since that is parsing the weather
                        for i in 0..<result.hourly.count {
                                result.hourly[i].id = UUID()
                        }
                        
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.weatherData = result
    
                        }
                        
                    }catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
                dataTask.resume()
            }
           }
        
        
        
        
        
    }//func getWeatherData
    
}
```

My Model

```
struct Weather: Decodable {
 
    var current: Current
    var hourly: [Current]
    
    //Hourly is an arrary of weather responses (i.e. Current). It parses the data because the arrary is similar to Current properties
    
}


struct Current: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID?
    var dt: Double
    var temp: Double
    var feels_like: Double
    var weather: [WeatherInfo]
    
}


struct WeatherInfo: Decodable {
    var description: String
}
```

Right now this is just a rough view and will update the look of it but for now I’m putting it as a list. I only want 12 hours of the hourly temperature rather than the 48 hours

View

```
List(model.weatherData?.hourly ?? [] ) {
                            hour in
                            Text("\(Constants.dtConversion(hour.dt)), \(Constants.tempToString(hour.temp))")
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the _first_ (up to) 12 items in the array, like self.weatherData = Weather(current: result.current, hourly: Array(result.hourly.prefix(12))) ?

Comment: Or if you need some middle set of 12, self.weatherData = Weather(current: result.current, hourly: Array(result.hourly[startingElement ..< startingElement + 12)). Just be careful that you don't go out of bounds of the array.

Comment: @Shadowrun Yes, the first 12 items in the array. I appreciate the input!